# spring-jpa - creating query similar to in clause for nested entity id using ExampleMatcher for QueryByExampleExecutor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-commons

I was trying out Spring ExampleMatcher for creating a query that requires use of in clause and between clause.

```
public class A{
    private Long id;    
    private B b;
    private D d;
    private Date created;
}

public class B {
    private Long id;
    private C c;
    private Long sequence;
}

public class C {
    private Long id;
    private String externalName;
}

public class D {
    private Long id;
}
```

I need to create a query that matches in clause on A.b.c.externalName, equal clause on A.d.id and between operator on A.b.sequence fields.

Is it possible to do create a query using ExampleMatcher that fulfills above scenario.

Sample HQL : `SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.d.id = :subscriberId AND a.b.c.externalName IN :externalNames and a.b.sequence between (:startSequence, :endSequence)`

Please help !

Comment: possible one : `SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.d.id = :subscriberId AND a.b.c.externalName IN (:externalNames) and a.b.sequence between :startSequence and  :endSequence`

Comment: sorry , but I was confused about how to create above filter using ExampleMatcher class.

Comment: It will work. You just implement the sample one to ExampleMatcher